# Queryselect element with variable name

Tags: javascript

Given the element

```
var inputAbilityName2 = document.getElementById('inputAbilityName2Id');
var inputAbilityName3 = document.getElementById('inputAbilityName3Id');
var inputAbilityName4 = document.getElementById('inputAbilityName4Id');
var inputAbilityName5 = document.getElementById('inputAbilityName5Id');
```

I then proceed with classList operations

```
inputAbilityName2.classList.replace('d-flex', 'd-none');
```

I need to select other elements by changing the number in the name, example I tried:

var idToChange = 5

```
('inputAbilityName' + idToChange).classList.replace('d-flex', 'd-none');
```

So that it will read inputAbilityName5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If variables are in global scope you can use `window` object to get them:

```
window["inputAbilityName" + idToChange].classList.replace('d-flex', 'd-none');
```

If they are not in global scope, than you should use an array to store the elements, or simply get the elements themselves:

```
document.getElementById('inputAbilityName' + idToChange + 'Id').classList.replace('d-flex', 'd-none');
```